# Express api with mongoose PUT

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have endpoint:

```
router.put('/:customerId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updatedCustomer = await Customer.updateOne(
            { _id: req.params.customerId },
            req.body,
            { new: true }
        );
        res.send(updatedCustomer);
    } catch {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});

const CustomerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String
})
```

and after put request with only name value in my object still exist name and surname. I thought that my surname value will be delete. It works fine or not?

Comment: Can you please clarify and add more details to your question

Answer (score 0):

In your schema definition do the following

```
const CustomerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String
},{
    strict:false
})
```

Comment: ok, it's situation if I pass extra value, but what's happen if I pass in put request object with 1 value instead 2 (e.g. only name). put expect the same object in request, if we do not send all values, the missing values should not be removed?